# Python3 about Loops Iteration multiple variable simple algorithm

Tags: python, loops, iteration

What i have to do is have T number of test cases which is how many time i will
obtain the average of "n" number of students in each test case and i need to display the average score for each test case and the highest mark in that test case and the name of student

If you can tell me the proper way to code this and explain why it has to be that way i will greatly appreciate it! I am lost

My code:

```
t = int(input("enter number of cases: "))
def casing(t):
    for case in range (1, t+1):
        n = int(input("enter number of students: "))
        def studentmarks(n):
            total = 0
            student = "none"
            for computetotal in range(1,n+1):
                student = input("please enter student name: ")
                mark = int(input("please enter mark: ")) 
                total = total+ mark
                highestmark = mark
                if studentmark(n) > mark:
                    highestmark = mark
                    achieve = student
                    return highestmark, acheive
            return total, studentmark()[0], studentmark()[1]
        average = float((studentmarks(n)[0])/ n)
        print("average: ", average, "highest: ",studentmark(n)[1], "student: ", studentmark(n)[2])
```

Comment: Your code has very strange indentation (with `studentmarks` being defined within the `casing` function, for example).  Was that introduced when copying and pasting, or is this how your code really looks?

Comment: i placed student mark to compare it with the other student but since i placed that line i started having errors. is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the code, as it is, would be much simpler to understand and debug without the function declarations. Unless you're doing functional-style programming (e.g. passing around function objects) there's rarely a good reason to use nested functions. Here you're defining the functions, then immediately calling them once, which is fairly pointless. So here's a simplified version of your code:

```
t = int(input("enter number of cases: "))
for _ in range (t):
    total = 0
    highest_mark = 0
    best_student = "none"

    n = int(input("enter number of students: "))

    for _ in range(n):
        student = input("please enter student name: ")
        mark = int(input("please enter mark: ")) 
        total = total+ mark
        if mark > highestmark:
            highestmark = mark
            beststudent = student

    average = total / n
    print("average: {}, highest: {}, student: {}"
          .format(average, highestmark beststudent))
```

I also eliminated the function named `studentmark` (with no "s") which your code was calling but never defined. I'm not sure if I correctly interpreted what it was supposed to be doing, but I think so. It certainly wouldn't have worked before.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons this isn't working - but the root cause seems to be because your highestmark is started off in the wrong place. It looks like you later expect the student name and mark to be in a tuple, which is a good idea - but you never actually make this tuple anywhere. So, make one, and call it `highest` - it replaces both the `student` and `highestmark` variables. Start it as `None` instead of `"none"` (which could actually be a valid student name!), so you have above the loop:

```
total = 0
highest = None
```

and change your "is this one higher than the highest" logic to this:

```
if highest is None or mark > highest[1]:
    highest = (name, mark)
```

Read as "if there is no highest student yet, or this one has a higher mark than the current highest, this one is the highest". Then you'll want the return to be:

```
return total, highest[0], highest[1]
```

But, since you only have a small amount of data (enough that it is feasible to have a user type it in at a console), then you can simplify this logic quite a bit. Read *all* of the data for a particular test case into a list of `(student, mark)` tuples, and then use Python's builtins to do the calculations:

```
def studentmarks(n):
    marks = []
    for _ in range(n):
       student = input("please enter student name: ")
       mark = int(input("please enter mark: ")) 
       marks.append(student, mark)
    return marks

# Calculations
marks = studentmarks(5)
print('Average: ', sum(result[1] for result in marks)/len(marks))
print('Highest: ', max(marks, key=lambda s: s[1])
```

Seeding it with:

```
>>> marks
[('Fred', 4), ('Wilma', 10), ('Barney', 8), ('Wilma', 7), ('Pebbles', 6)]
```

Gives an average of 7.0, and a maximum of `('Wilma', 10)`.

Comment: Wow these are all good! where can i learn these step by step< since i dont know where i can learn these.